# Pass state objects to external function from React component function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to JS, React and am not able to pass state objects from React Component function to a external function.

This is my FormPage parent component method 'formSubmit ' from where i am making the call

```
import { formValidate } from './FormHelpers';

class FormPage extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      fields: {
        userName: "", userAttributes: []
      },
      errors: {}
    }
  };

formSubmit = (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
const formErrors = formValidate(this.state.fields);
....
.....
}
```

Below is my function formValidate defined in FormHelpers.js file:

```
export const formValidate = ({fieldsIn}) => {
    let errors = {};
    let formIsValid = true;
    let fields = fieldsIn;


    if (!fields["userName"]) {
        formIsValid = false;
        errors["userName"] = "Please enter metadata";
    }

    if (typeof fields["userName"] !== "undefined") {
        if (!fields["userName"].match(/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/)) {
            formIsValid = false;
            errors["userName"] = "Please enter alphabet char only";
        }
    }

   
    let formErrors = {
        errors: errors, formIsValid: formIsValid
    };
    return formErrors;
    }
```

I would like to call formValidate() function with state.fields as argument and return formErrors as object back to React.

While executing, am getting below error in FormHelpers.js
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'userName' of undefined

I don't seem to understand my mistake here. Can you please guide me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You call `formValidate(this.state.fields)`, and the function parameter destructures the property `({fieldsIn})`. So you're attempting to access the property `this.state.fields.fieldsIn.userName`, where presumably `fieldsIn` doesn't exist.

Comment: Use formValidate = (fieldsIn) instead of ({fieldsIn})